# Infinity norm inequality

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ given with $a_i = \pm 1$. Let $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k e^{ikx}$. I need to prove that $\lVert f \rVert_\infty \geq \sqrt{n}$ where $\lVert f \rVert_\infty$ is defined as the maximum value of $|f|$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

**Attempt:** I tried experimenting with all $a_i$ being $1$ or $-1$ but I couldn't generalize it. Any hint would be appreciated. No need for the full solution.

Comment: This reminds me of [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2561541/8157) of mine. Unfortunately I am not sure this is going to be useful for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Define $g(x) = f(2 \pi x)$. Note that $\|g\|_\infty \geq \|g\|_2$, where $\|g\|_\infty$ is the maximum of $|g(x)|$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and
$$
\|g\|_2 = \left[\int_0^1 |g(x)|^2\,dx\right]^{1/2}.
$$

---

**Second Hint:** Let $f_k(x) = e^{2 \pi ikx}$. Verify that the vectors $f_1,\dots,f_n$ form an orthonormal set relative to the inner product
$$
\langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) \overline{g(x)}\,dx,
$$
where $\bar z$ denote the complex conjugate of $z$. Use this to conclude that
$$
\left\| \sum _{k=1}^n a_k f_k\right\|_2  = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. So basically I need to show that $\lVert g \rVert_2 \geq \sqrt{n}$, correct?

Comment: @mathemagician101 Yes. In fact, you can show that $\|g\|_2 = \sqrt{n}$

Comment: I don't see how to do it. Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: @mathemagician101 See my latest edit.

Comment: Very nice! It didn't occur to me to use Parseval's identity.